# override default focus with css or reseting it

Tags: javascript, html, css, focus

I want something like `css reset`, but only for the `:focus`. If there's none of this yet, would be good to know the possible properties to reset(override) in order to make new `:focus` that will override the previously one(set by the web-site css). For example, `z-index` may effect on `:focus` for some specific elements in some browsers. So the `:focus` should include `z-index` with some huge number and in order to work it should include `position` too. perhaps it's wrong example, but I think you got the idea here.

Answer (score 4):

You may want to post some code with some examples of problems that you are having in a jsfiddle or in the question.

That said, there are some elements that tend to get default styling for :focus in the browser - input, a.  There is some great information [here](https://www.kirupa.com/html5/changing_the_default_focus_styles.htm) about potential fixes, for instance:

```
/* put universal focus changes here */
*:focus {
  outline: none;
}

/* put anchor focus changes here */
a:focus {
  ...
}

/* put input focus changes here */
input:focus {
  ...
}
```

I'm not certain what you are trying to accomplish with the z-index setting, but you could handle it as above.

Comment: It wasn't the answer to tho op question, but `outline: none` was what I was looking for. Thank you!